# Prefixing protocol for address in ssh and lftp

Tags: ssh, lftp

I'm using ssh to connect to my remote server. I'm able to do so fine using the regular SSH commands, but using lftp to connect requires prepending sftp:// to the address for it to work.
What's the difference between using the address (hostname@domain-name) versus prepending sftp://?

Answer (score 1):

The `sftp` command-line utility only supports one file-transfer protocol, [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). Similarly, the `scp` utility only supports [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy). If you invoke one of those utilities to transfer a file, it's a given that you want the utility to use the one protocol that it supports.

[`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) on the other hand supports half a dozen different file transfer protocols. From the link:

> lftp  can  handle  several file access methods - FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, HFTP, FISH, SFTP and
>          file ...Besides  FTP-like  protocols,  lftp has support for BitTorrent protocol as `torrent' command.
>          Seeding is also supported.

So if you invoke `lftp` to transfer a file, it makes sense that you'd have to tell it somehow what protocol you want to use.

Beyond that, `sftp` and `lftp` are different programs, with different capabilities, written and maintained by different groups of people. There's no reason to expect them to accept the exact same command-line parameters.